# Параметры функции в pyqt5

Tags: python, функции, pyqt5, классы, pyqt

Как решить ошибку 'Unresolved reference' в 61-63 строках? Пытался решить проблему добавлением self и ряда других параметров, но всё тщетно. Ошибка в том, что я не не до конца понимаю, как работают функции в классах или это что-то другое? Заранее благодарен.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from random import randint as r
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    a = ['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага']
    t1 = a[r(0, 2)]
    a.remove(t1)
    t2 = a[r(0, 1)]
    a.remove(t2)
    t3 = str(a)

    def one(self, t1):
        self.text_1.setText(t1)
        self.text_1.move(150, 120)
        self.text_1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

    def two(self, t2):
        self.text_2.setText(t2)
        self.text_2.move(150, 160)
        self.text_2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

    def three(self, t3):
        self.text_3.setText(t3)
        self.text_3.move(150, 200)
        self.text_3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('SSS')
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 400, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet('color: black')

        self.text_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text1.move(50, 120)
        self.text1.setText('Tommy:')
        self.text1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text2.move(50, 160)
        self.text2.setText('Hanna:')
        self.text2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text3.move(50, 200)
        self.text3.setText('Jo:')
        self.text3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.move(150, 50)
        self.btn.setText('TOUCH')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.one(t1))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.two(t2))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.three(t3))

        self.ent = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.ent.move(100, 100)


def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application()
```

Comment: Советую использовать компоновщики, это улучшит интерфейс, убережет от костылей и, когда будет работать, поднимет настроение :) Компоновщики это `Q*Layout`, такие как: QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QFormLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил, чтобы запускалось.

Места, где менял, в коде выделил, *но заметил, что выбор фигуры определяется только один раз, что кажется неправильным. Как правильно смотрите ниже в варианте 2 (я там попутно упростил код для случайных значений)*

**Вариант 1**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from random import randint as r
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        a = ['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага']
        t1 = a[r(0, 2)]
        a.remove(t1)
        t2 = a[r(0, 1)]
        a.remove(t2)
        t3 = a[0]
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.setWindowTitle('SSS')
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 400, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet('color: black')

        self.text_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text1.move(50, 120)
        self.text1.setText('Tommy:')
        self.text1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text2.move(50, 160)
        self.text2.setText('Hanna:')
        self.text2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text3.move(50, 200)
        self.text3.setText('Jo:')
        self.text3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.move(150, 50)
        self.btn.setText('TOUCH')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.one(t1))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.two(t2))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.three(t3))
        #                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.ent = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.ent.move(100, 100)

    def one(self, t1):
        self.text_1.setText(t1)
        self.text_1.move(150, 120)
        self.text_1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

    def two(self, t2):
        self.text_2.setText(t2)
        self.text_2.move(150, 160)
        self.text_2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

    def three(self, t3):
        self.text_3.setText(t3)
        self.text_3.move(150, 200)
        self.text_3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))


def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application()
```

**Вариант 2**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import random
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('SSS')
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 400, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet('color: black')

        self.text_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text1.move(50, 120)
        self.text1.setText('Tommy:')
        self.text1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text2.move(50, 160)
        self.text2.setText('Hanna:')
        self.text2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text3.move(50, 200)
        self.text3.setText('Jo:')
        self.text3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.move(150, 50)
        self.btn.setText('TOUCH')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self._on_touch)
        #                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.ent = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.ent.move(100, 100)

    def _on_touch(self):
        a = ['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага']
        random.shuffle(a)
        t1, t2, t3 = a

        self.one(t1)
        self.two(t2)
        self.three(t3)
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def one(self, t1):
        self.text_1.setText(t1)
        self.text_1.move(150, 120)
        self.text_1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

    def two(self, t2):
        self.text_2.setText(t2)
        self.text_2.move(150, 160)
        self.text_2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

    def three(self, t3):
        self.text_3.setText(t3)
        self.text_3.move(150, 200)
        self.text_3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))


def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```